# Polymer PHP post 404 not found

Tags: php, post, polymer

I am working on a section in my code that is running with Polymer. I created a form that is supposed to POST to a PHP file in a directory (named API) that communicates with our SQL. Instead of successfully sending post data to the `register-wine.php` file, I get a not found 404 error that comes with a few other Polymer file errors. Any idea why these errors are occurring?

Offending HTML file:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-form/iron-form.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-input/iron-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">

<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="wc-view2">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Register Wine</h1>
      <div left>
            <!---  <wc-register id="wc-register-wine" method = "post" action="api/register-wine.php" ></div> --->
            <div id ="register-wine-container">
                <form is="iron-form" id="register-wine-form" method="post" disable-native-validation-ui action="../api/register-wine.php">
                    <h3>Insert Wine Data! </h3>
                    <paper-input-container>
                        <input is="iron-input" id = "inputProducer" name ="producer" type ="text" placeholder = "Producer" required>
                        <!---Can insert Icon for prettiness, but will later, lets get functionality-->
                    </paper-input-container>

                    <paper-input-container>
                        <input is="iron-input" id = "inputName" name ="wname" type ="text" placeholder = "Wine Name" required>
                        <!---Can insert Icon for prettiness, but will later, lets get functionality-->
                    </paper-input-container>

                    <paper-input-container>
                        <input is="iron-input" id = "inputGrape" name ="grape" type ="text" placeholder = "Grape (Optional)">
                        <!---Can insert Icon for prettiness, but will later, lets get functionality-->
                    </paper-input-container>

                    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Wine Style">
                        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" name = "wine_styles">
                          <paper-item>Sparkling White</paper-item>
                          <paper-item>Sparkling Rosé</paper-item>
                          <paper-item>Stil White</paper-item>
                          <paper-item>Still Red</paper-item>
                          <paper-item>Dessert</paper-item>
                          <paper-item>Fortified White</paper-item>
                          <paper-item>Fortified Red</paper-item>
                        </paper-listbox>
                      </paper-dropdown-menu>

                      <paper-input-container>
                        <input is="iron-input" id = "inputVintage" name ="vintage" type ="number" placeholder = "Vintage (YYYY)" required>
                        <!---Can insert Icon for prettiness, but will later, lets get functionality-->
                    </paper-input-container>

                    <paper-input-container>
                        <input is="iron-input" id = "inputCountry" name ="country" type ="text" placeholder = "Country" required>
                        <!---Can insert Icon for prettiness, but will later, lets get functionality-->
                    </paper-input-container>

                    <paper-input-container>
                        <input is="iron-input" id = "inputState" name ="state" type ="text" placeholder = "State/Province" required>
                        <!---Can insert Icon for prettiness, but will later, lets get functionality-->
                    </paper-input-container>

                    <paper-input-container>
                        <input is="iron-input" id = "inputRegion" name ="region" type ="text" placeholder = "Region (Optional)">
                        <!---Can insert Icon for prettiness, but will later, lets get functionality-->
                    </paper-input-container>

                    <paper-input-container>
                        <input is="iron-input" id = "inputSubRegion" name ="sRegion" type ="text" placeholder = "Sub-Region (Optional)">
                        <!---Can insert Icon for prettiness, but will later, lets get functionality-->
                    </paper-input-container>

                    <paper-input-container>
                        <input is="iron-input" id = "inputVintage" name ="vintage" type ="number" placeholder = "Alcohol Percentage (##)" required>
                        <!---Can insert Icon for prettiness, but will later, lets get functionality-->
                    </paper-input-container>
                      <button name="regWine" type="submit">Register Wine</button>
                </form>

            </div>

          </div>
          <div right></div>

    </div>
  </template>
  <script language = "javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
  </script>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'wc-view2'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Here is my file structure: 
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhEfY.png)

Here is the error, and what the error contains(following first line):

```
iron-request.html:304 POST http://localhost:8080/api/register-wine.php 404 (Not Found)

send @ iron-request.html:304

generateRequest @ iron-ajax.html:455

submit @ iron-form.html:251

_onSubmit @ iron-form.html:262

handler @ polymer.html:561
```

Comment: Is your l ocal webserver set up to run PHP? What happens if you navigate directly to the offending path?

Comment: Yea the php is mostly running stuff in the background, I placed an echo into it and it seems to be working.

Comment: What does that mean which php script is running in the background and which php script did you put an echo in.  The error messages says your web server returned a 404, normally meaning it couldn't find your script.

Comment: Well, when I navigate to it directly, my browser just downloads the page. I tested a normal php page that echos something, and it seems to work. So my local webserver is able to run php. Do you think maybe polymer isn't routing the POST correctly?

Comment: I suggest isolating your problem by removing Polymer from the equation: create an HTML page with a bit of jQuery code that sends an AJAX request to your API URL and in the callback `console.log` something returning from server. Once you verify it works - then look into Polymer.